Katalon Studio, Testcases disappear after pushing code and open other project
Recently, i made plenty changes and new testcases in my project. Then, i commited and pushed my code to my repository branch in Bitbucket. After that, i got some error like “Rejected bla bla bla”. But when i checked my repository branch in Bitbucket, there was no update there. So i tried to reopen the same project that i cloned into filesystem. But all the changes i made today totally disappear and. Is there any chances to recover all of my testcases?
I opened all project files in my filesystem and there was none of them provides my recent testcase that i've made today. So, i hope there was a chance to bring them back. Because i think it should be store locally in my computer right?

Please paste the correct “Rejected bla bla bla” error.
